# Как отключить ошибку C4700 «Использована неинициализированная локальная переменная»?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, c++

Не могу запустить рабочий проект под Visual Studio 2013 из-за этой ошибки. Проект старый, делался еще под Visual Studio 6.0. Видимо, там выдавалось предупреждение вместо ошибки.

Переменных много. Может быть, все-таки можно обойти эту ошибку, не инициализируя их все?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В свойствах проекта - свойства конфигурации - С/С++ - создание кода - проверка безопасности - Отключить проверку безопасности (/GS-)